# Auto Complete Searching

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I am working with asp.net, i want some suggessions to implement search functionality with auto complete. Now i am using sql server as the backend in that i am retrieving 4 columns from three tables and sending those as parameters for searching. Now my problem is how to send those four fields at a time for sarching. And how to write the code for searching based ob those fields.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Use AJAX Autocomplete

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Question is not very clear but what i can sugeest to get the best performance if data is not that huge you can cache data in async mode while page load and use ajax auto complete to give user best experience.